# How can i make header and footer like the image i send..?

Tags: html, css, header, footer

i upload an image here i wanna make my header and footer like the image i send anyone can help me with that ..?

in footer i have 5 button in middle of the item one of them have background and icon looks like image how can i make that ..?

and i have a header i wanna  make that like image to .

anyone can give me a code or something..?

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCRlO.jpg)
this is my image

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: You should start by learning HTML and CSS.

Comment: At first, learn how to ask on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an idea which you can do this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style type="text/css">

    .header {
        background-color: black;
        width: 500px;
        height: 70px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 60%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    }

    .footer {
        width: 500px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        background-color: #dbd0d0;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .fa.fa-home {
        padding: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #60b75f;
        border-radius: 100%;
        color: white;
        top: -18px;
    }

    .fa.fa-volume-up {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .fa.fa-map-o {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }

</style>

<div class="header">

</div>



<div class="footer">

    <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-map-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you i try your code and now i understand what i have to do

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two Background for Header. The Parent Class have the Heart Image background with position relative and The child have white curve shape background with absolute position.

For Footer the green icon is going upward will have a 1 more different class with respect to other icon, on the base of this class you will style it.

Html and css for footer icon written below, i am using font awesome icon for example now, you can use icon or image as per your requirement.

/* Html */

```
<a href=""><span class="bg-color"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
```

/* Css for icon style. Adjust top in css as per your requirement */

```
span.bg-color {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #09d0bf;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```